# Performance difference with using 'mysql_connect()' and without using it

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

To interpret a normal PHP file (without using MySQL) it takes about **0.01** Milliseconds. But if you add `mysql_connect()` or `mysqli_connect()` or any other function to connect to a DB it takes much more time to interpret it. (usually about **1.05** Miliseconds).

I've tested so many times, the problem occurs when connecting to the database. No matter how many queries you run, they're super-fast. But Why connecting to a database is slower than querying from it.

What's the problem here ? What's the fastest way to connect to MySQL ?

*I am using XAMP with Apache & MySQL on Windows 7*

Comment: This is unexpected result, its better to install web server components individually...

Comment: Oh yes and always use `mysqli_*` in preference to the deprecated `mysql_*` functions :-)

Comment: PDO is probably the best bet. Use that before you end up with a ton of technical debt because `mysql_query` is scheduled to be removed in future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to MySQL you are opening a socket connection.  This is routed through the network layer of your operating system, and there is a handshake to perform for every connection where the client (your code) passes the username and password, and the database engine has to validate those credentials.  Then the client opens a connection to a specific database.

This is known as the "overhead" of opening a database connection.

The best solutions are, (a) don't worry about a 1ms delay in your code, there are probably other ways you can get that performance benefit back, and/or the user won't even notice that 1ms; or (b) if you really really must have it micro-optimised, then you only connect once per page, or not at all if you don't need the connection on that particular page.

Comment: Some frameworks lazy load connections and only connect once its actually needed. Persistent connections could also be used, but you have to be careful as to not overload mysql with too many connections.

Comment: Thanks, That may be the problem that i was searching around the web. Some software problems. Isn't there a way to keep that connection, without connecting it every-time a user requests ?

Comment: That's what "persistent connections" means :-)